# Javascript get div by it's background image?

Tags: javascript, html, css

I have div that has this style

```
<div style="position:absolute;top:0px;left:0px;width:2004px;height:700px;background-color:undefined;background-image:url(https://taxirondo.net-informatika.com/wp-content/uploads/2018/04/slajder1.jpg);background-repeat:no-repeat;background-size:cover;background-position:center center;"></div>
```

How can I get this div and appand it with another div(by its background image)? This is automatic generated div and I can't add class or id.

Comment: Does it absolutely have to be selected by the background image? Do you have nothing else at hand, like a specific position inside a specific ancestor element, or something like that?

Answer (score 5):

You could use css attribute selector:

```
document.querySelector('[style*="background-image:url(https://taxirondo.net-informatika.com/wp-content/uploads/2018/04/slajder1.jpg)"]');
```

This way you will select the first ocurrence of an element with the supplied background image. No need to iterate thru a collection of elements.

```js
console.log(document.querySelector('[style="background-image:url(https://taxirondo.net-informatika.com/wp-content/uploads/2018/04/slajder1.jpg)"]'));
```

```html
<div style="background-image:url(https://taxirondo.net-informatika.com/wp-content/uploads/2018/04/slajder1.jpg)">Selected DIV</div>
```

More about [attribute selectors](https://www.w3.org/TR/selectors-3/#attribute-selectors)

Answer (score 3):

One way is to get all the `div`s which have style assigned and then find the element which has the specified as its `style.backgroundImage`:

```js
const divs = document.querySelectorAll('div[style]');
const url = 'https://taxirondo.net-informatika.com/wp-content/uploads/2018/04/slajder1.jpg';

const elem = Array.from(divs)
  .find(item => item.style.backgroundImage.includes(url));

console.log(elem);
```

```html
<div style="position:absolute;top:0px;left:0px;width:2004px;height:700px;background-color:undefined;background-image:url(https://taxirondo.net-informatika.com/wp-content/uploads/2018/04/slajder1.jpg);background-repeat:no-repeat;background-size:cover;background-position:center center;"></div>
```

Please understand the implications of this code before proceeding:

1. It does a check if the element's background contains the URL. Doesn't check the exact value.
2. It has to iterate through the available elements to find the desired one, which may be a costly operation when there are many such elements.

Comment: It can be optimised(?) this way: 
`querySelectorAll('div[style*="background-image"][style*="https://taxirondo.net-informatika.com/wp-content/uploads/2018/04/slajder1.jpg"]')`